# How do I crop and align a fade-out SVG mask with absolute units to the bottom right in Firefox?

Tags: css, svg

In Firefox (where I don't have line-clamp), I want to achieve a fade-out gradient effect for the bottom right corner. See sceenshot/codepen in firefox. I've built this as an inline SVG, but I've had to hard-code the positions of everything. How can I make this lower right corner fade out **no matter how large the green box is?** I'd expect the gradient to have absolute units, but that for the mask to allow for arbitrary sizes of total area.

codepen (FF only): https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EGjeBm

[image: The last 3em horizontally fade out on the word "vitae"]

```html
<svg height="4em" width="8em">
  <mask id="maskSource" class="MaskType" maskContentUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <rect x="5em" y="3em" width="3em" height="1em" style="fill:url(#grad);" />
    <rect x="0" y="3em" width="5em" height="1em" style="fill:black;" />
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="8em" height="3em" style="fill:black;" />
    <linearGradient id="grad" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:black;" />
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:transparent;" />
    </linearGradient>
  </mask>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox"`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/masking.html#MaskElementMaskContentUnitsAttribute) and give the size as either percentages or fractions of 1.

```css
div {
  mask-image: url(#maskSource);
  width: 8em;
  height: 4em;
  line-height: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 5em;
}
section {
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: inline-block;
}
.MaskType {
  mask-type: alpha;
}
svg {
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 5em;
}
body{background:pink;}
```

```html
<section><div>Maecenas ultrices, nisl vitae maximus facilisis, dolor velit porttitor odio, vitae pharetra</div></section>

<svg width="0" height="0">
  <mask id="maskSource" class="MaskType" maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">
    <rect x="0.625" y="0.75" width="0.375" height="0.25" style="fill:url(#grad);" />
    <rect x="0" y="0.75" width="0.625" height="0.25" style="fill:black;" />
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="1" height="0.75" style="fill:black;" />
    <linearGradient id="grad" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:black;" />
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:transparent;" />
    </linearGradient>
  </mask>
</svg>
```